# Excel if cell in range contains specific text, export and compile on new worksheet

Tags: excel

I am working with a decent size data set in excel. It has 5 columns and up to 5000 rows of data. Column A data is irrelevant to my goal as is Column B and E. The two columns I care about are, Column C which is numbers only in content, and column D which contains text (comments left about the numbers in Column C. For example, the cell D2 would state: “Machine is acting erratically and repairs have not been attempted. Issue has been ongoing for three months and multiple service call requests have been submitted.”

I am curious to know if there is a formula I can use to review ALL cells in Column D to determine if certain words are being used, such as “machine” or “not attempted”, and in some cases, BOTH of those words/phrases, and if the text IS contained in Column D, can the data of column C be compiled and moved into a new sheet to form a list.

Another way of looking at it, Review Column D and if key words or phrases exist, export the cell from column C and the same row to a new sheet in a list. Is this something that is outside of a mere formula and would require going into the macros to try and perform or?

So far I’ve managed to get Excel to count the number of times the phrases and words I’m looking for can be found, but I would like for it to be able to locate the referenced logs and move the log numbers into it’s own sheet.

Comment: An array formula can certainly do this, but vba would be better tool.  The array formula would iterate at least 10,000 times per formula and would need 5000 formula.  This would slow the processing time and may hang Excel.  Better to use variant arrays in vba.

Comment: The biggest crossroads I’m hitting is that I can’t install other software on my computer at work.

Comment: vba is the native programming language for Excel, it comes with it.  So, unless your IT has locked it out or has a policy against it, it already exists on your computer.

Comment: Thanks Scott! I’ll start taking a look into that.